# getting empty list inside IActionResult on button submit - razor pages partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to pass a list of ids to `IActionResult` on button `submit`. The ids are coming from dropdown list selections. My view is a `partial-view` getting a model object. **the problem is right now when i submit, the list is empty always.**

I have read that we can not pass a list to controller! then what are the possible approaches, I am literally stuck on this for a day!

> I have only pasted part of the code i felt is necessary to show,
> please let me know if you want to see other code.

**View.cshtml**

```
    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="UpdateComponent">
.
.
.
        @{ 
            var value1 = 0;
            var value2 = 0; 
            var value3 =0;
        }
        <!-- asp-items="New plant SelectList"-->
        <select class="form-control Shoplist News-plant-select_1 mt-2" data-search="true"  asp-for="@value1">
            <option value="">Bitte auswählen</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <!-- asp-items="New plant SelectList"-->
        <select class="form-control Shoplist News-plant-select_2 mt-2" data-search="true" asp-for="@value2">
            <option value="">Bitte auswählen</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <!-- asp-items="New plant SelectList"-->
        <select class="form-control Shoplist News-plant-select_3 mt-2" data-search="true" asp-for="@value3">
            <option value="">Bitte auswählen</option>
        </select>

        @{

            Model.newsletterSubComponents.Add(new Models.NewsletterSubComponents() { NewPlantArticleId = value1 });
            Model.newsletterSubComponents.Add(new Models.NewsletterSubComponents() { NewPlantArticleId = value2 });
            Model.newsletterSubComponents.Add(new Models.NewsletterSubComponents() { NewPlantArticleId = value3 });

        }
        <input type="hidden" name="value1" value="@Model.newsletterSubComponents" asp-for="@Model.newsletterSubComponents"/>
.
.
.
<input type="submit" value="Speichern" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

**controller**

```
        public IActionResult OnPostUpdateComponent(NewsletterComponents component, int? newsId, int? shortArticleId,
            List<NewsletterSubComponents> newsletterSubComponents, int? test)
        {
                                               ^
                                               |
                                          list empty

.
.
.          
}
```

[image]

**i populate dropdown lists using ajax**

```
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, element) {
            $('.News-plant-select_1').append($("<option>").val(element.Id).text(element.NameGerman));
            console.log(element.NameGerman);
            $('.News-plant-select_2').append($("<option>").val(element.Id).text(element.NameGerman));
            console.log(element.NameGerman);
        });;

        //remove spinner
        $('.News-plant-select').removeClass("spinner-border");

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive ids, I think you can just use List< int > to receive it, also keep the parameter name the same as that in select element. I made an example based on your codes:

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="UpdateComponent">
    @{
        List<NewsletterSubComponents> newsletterSubComponents = new List<NewsletterSubComponents>
        {
            new NewsletterSubComponents{ NewPlantArticleId = 1, NewPlantArticleName = "AAA"},
            new NewsletterSubComponents{ NewPlantArticleId = 2, NewPlantArticleName = "BBB"},
            new NewsletterSubComponents{ NewPlantArticleId = 3, NewPlantArticleName = "CCC"}
        };
        var selectList = new SelectList(newsletterSubComponents, "NewPlantArticleId", "NewPlantArticleName");
    }

    <!-- asp-items="New plant SelectList"-->
    <select name="newsletterSubComponentIds" class="form-control Shoplist News-plant-select_1 mt-2" data-search="true" asp-items="@selectList" >
        <option value="">Bitte auswählen</option>
    </select>
    <br />

    <!-- asp-items="New plant SelectList"-->
    <select name="newsletterSubComponentIds" class="form-control Shoplist News-plant-select_2 mt-2" data-search="true" asp-items="@selectList">
        <option value="">Bitte auswählen</option>
    </select>
    <br />

    <!-- asp-items="New plant SelectList"-->
    <select name="newsletterSubComponentIds" class="form-control Shoplist News-plant-select_3 mt-2" data-search="true" asp-items="@selectList">
        <option value="">Bitte auswählen</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Speichern" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks @mj1313 for the answer, i appreciate your time. one small thing though. My list is coming from javascript actually. I have updated my code with javascript snapshot.

Comment: in my case, the three dropdowns get populate using javascript. Then what i want is to store selected int values into a list of size 3 and pass them to controller.

Comment: There is no difference using javascript, since they are the same after rendered to html. You just need to add a name attribute to the select element, because model binding is based on the name.